# InternetOpenA EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: exception, assembly, x86-64

I do call InternetOpenA in assembler

It is failing with `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` on this **command**:

```
movdqa xmmword ptr [rsp + 0x20], xmm0
```

source

```
start:

    sub rsp,30h

    lea rcx, [userAgent]
    mov rdx,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT
    mov r8,0
    mov r9,0
    mov qword ptr ds:[rsp+20],0
    call qword ptr ds:[<&InternetOpenA>] <---------------
```

Comment: You misaligned the stack.

Comment: I agree completely with @Jester.  In the future you may find folks are better able to assist you if you include a bit more contextual code.  While I believe Jester is correct, we really don't know what `RSP` looks like before your `SUB RSP,30h`, so it is a guess.  More code leading up to the problem would make this easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

i edit 1st post

its entry point

i will add

```
sub rsp, 8
```

and its work

```
start:

    sub rsp, 8
    sub rsp,30h

    lea rcx, [userAgent]
    mov rdx,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT
    mov r8,0
    mov r9,0
    mov qword ptr ds:[rsp+20],0
    call qword ptr ds:[<&InternetOpenA>] <---------------
```

but i dont understand why stack not aligned at start